# Stop Webforms loading memberships in the messages section for 'existing contacts'?

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm

We have a Webform that creates a single membership. We've set it to use the 'existing contact' which very helpfully pre-fills the webform with the existing user's details - or with the details corresponding to the contact's checksum from a CiviMail. This is all brilliant so far!

However, when the page loads it also shows all the contact's existing memberships. And it shows them in the page's system 'messages' block.

In our use case we don't want to see existing memberships. And even if we did we'd want to see them in a webform component that we can control the behaviour of. When they appear in the system messages block it looks like an extra communication to the user and is rather confusing.

So, is it possible to prevent them from loading at all? Or at least have them load as a component of the webform rather than displaying in the messages block?

We are on Drupal 7.58, Civi 5.0.0

Comment: You can try something similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942785/alter-messages-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 2):

You could add a simple css hack to your webform which sets system messages on the front page of the form to `display: none`. That's not a perfect solution because it will hide *all* of them, but it's something.

Comment: yes just use css to hide it; we like it/use it; this is the first time I’ve ever heard of anyone trying to hide it

Answer (score 0):

There is no way from preventing this message unless you are a developer and write your own drupal module which hides this message.

Comment: I've looked at @jackrabbithanna's comment above and that comes close... is there anywhere else that actually shows the code necessary for this module? No problems if not - just wondering if it's already been done. Thanks!

Comment: You can take a look at the webform_civicrm code at https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm